# jQuery - how to append new data into a div full of boxes with "position: absolute"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's have a following HTML structure:

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: Apx; top: Bpx;">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

I am using on this page also endless pagination, so when I click on the "Load more" button, then is called this JS action:

> $('.items').append(...new data covered in ".item" divs...);

The data are loaded, but they are displayed on the top of the **.items** div => the "old" data (**.item** divs) are overlap by the new ones.
For sure, I would like to display the new data wrapped again in **.item** divs below the previous ones (with **position: absolute;**), but how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: What's the css position of the 'items' div?

Comment: And why are you using an absolutely positioned div? can't they just show up underneath each other relatively?

Comment: Because the page use Pinterest-like layout.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are appending the new divs dynamically, you can set their top offset dynamically, something like this:

```
var topValue = $('.items').position().top + $('.items').outerHeight(true) + 'px';
var newDiv = ... // Populate your new div, setting the "top: Bpx" value to topValue
$('.items').append(newDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then I would recommend that you make the `.items` div the part that is absolutely positioned, while you make the `.item` elements relatively positioned within it. This should help them stack correctly when more are added while maintaining position.

Another option would be to add a div around these elements to align them.